# How can I loop through an object with a specific condition and return an array of its values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of all items ids:

`const allIds = ['a1gb', 'f4qa', 'i9w9']`

I also have an object with it's properties having those ids as keys:

```
const byId = {
  a1gb: {
    whatever1
  },
  anyOtherIdThatIDontNeed: {
    whatever444
  },
  f4qa: {
    whatever2
  },
  i9w9: {
    whatever3
  }
}
```

What is the most common way to return an array that would look like

```
[ { whatever1 }, { whatever2 }, { whatever3 } ]
```

and skip the Ids I don't want in my final array?

This a log of the array with the ids:

[image: array with ids]

This is a log of the object from which I need to return an array with the values of the keys from that array of ids skipping the ones I don't need:

[image: object with keyes]

P.S. Problem is that in that return array from the map function I get undefined when it encounters "anyOtherIdThatIDontNeed:".

[image: undefined]

P.P.S.[ ANSWER ] - The array of Ids had ids that do not match object's keys and that is why I was getting undefined.

Comment: Does your array of allIds also contain unwanted Ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var result = allids.map(val => ({byId[val]}))`

I would suggest this way, try the below code if the array also has unwanted ids.

`var result = allids.map(val => ({byId[val]})).filter(val => val?true:false)`

Comment: You need braces around your return, or it's a code block, and not returning anything.

Comment: you can also try it using reduce function:

allIds.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   return [...acc, byId2[curr]]
}, []).filter(Boolean)

Comment: He doesn't need a filter function as you can see in the example provided the array contains required ids only I think his explanation means to skip ids that are not in array from byId object

Comment: The issue is that in that returned array from the map function I get undefined when it encounters "anyOtherIdThatIDontNeed:".

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu Can you post the code and log of the object in the question please

Comment: Did you try the code with filter that I gave you, and I suspect that the array has Ids which are not in object causing to return undefined...

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS True indeed, I've been working with these Id's for a few days and I just didn't see that the Ids don't match. Should I delete this question because of my mistakes?

Comment: Choice is yours either delete or update so that it matches what the best answer is that you found and anyone else coming for help may find useful